# Laravel Livewire Multiple Dropdown Item(Product) Selection Problem on Order page

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

It's an order management page. We are using livewire for this page. As it's an order page we have to add multiple products on this page and have to calculate discount&price per product.
The problem is **when we select the 2nd product from the dropdown list the UI is changed!**

Here is the UI code

```
<div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-form-label">Select Product</label>
            <select wire:model="selectedProductId" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">Select Product</option>
                @foreach ($products as $product)
                    <option @if(in_array($product->id, $selectedProductIds)) disabled @endif value="{{ $product->id }}">{{ $product->title }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            @error('productId')
                <p style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</p>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@forelse($orders as $order)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="product">Product</label>
                <input class="form-control @error('quantity') is-invalid @enderror"" type="text" value="{{ $order['productName']}}"
                id="product">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                <input class="form-control @error('quantity') is-invalid @enderror"" type="text" wire:model="orders.{{ $loop->index }}.quantity"
                id="quantity" placeholder="Enter quantity">
                @error('quantity')
                    <p style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="unit">Unit</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ $order['unit'] }}" id="unit" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="unit">Unit Price</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ $order['price'] }}" id="unit" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label">Discount</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model="orders.{{ $loop->index }}.discount" class="form-control @error('discount') is-invalid @enderror" id="purchasePrice" placeholder="Enter discount" >
                @error('discount')
                    <p style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label">Amount</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model="orders.{{ $loop->index }}.amount" class="form-control @error('amount') is-invalid @enderror" id="amount" placeholder="Individual amount">
                @error('amount')
                    <p style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 mt-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button wire:click.prevent="remove({{ $loop->index }})">Remove{{ $loop->index }}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@empty 
    <p>No product added.</p>
@endforelse
```

Here is the livewire function for products and order

```
 public function updatedselectedProductId()
 {
    $product = Product::join('units', 'products.unit_id', 'units.id')
        ->where('products.id', $this->selectedProductId)->first();
    $this->orders[] = [
        'productId' => $product->id,
        'productName' => $product->title,
        'quantity' => $product->amount,
        'unit' => $product->unit,
        'discount' => 0,
        'price' => $product->sell_price,
        'amount' => $product->sell_price,
    ];
    $this->selectedProductIds[] = $this->selectedProductId;
    $this->selectedProductId = 0;
    $this->totalAmount += $product->sell_price;
}

public function updatedOrders($value, $name)
{
    if (Str::endsWith($name, '.quantity')) {
        $index = Str::before($name, '.');
        if (is_numeric($value)) {
            $this->orders[$index]['amount'] = $this->orders[$index]['price'] * $value;
        }
    }
    if (Str::endsWith($name, '.discount')) {
        $index = Str::before($name, '.');
        if (is_numeric($value)) {
            $amount = $this->orders[$index]['quantity'] * $this->orders[$index]['price'];
            $this->orders[$index]['amount'] = $amount - ($amount * $value / 100);
        }
    }
    $this->totalAmount += $this->orders[$index]['amount'];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full livewire code

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Order;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Admin\Order;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Models\Admin\Product;
use App\Models\Admin\Customer;
use App\Models\Admin\Supplier;
use App\Models\Admin\DeliveryAgent;

class Create extends Component
{
    public $title;
    public $email;
    public $phone;
    public $deliveryAddress;

    public $totalAmount;
    public $deliveryCharge;
    public $packagingCharge;
    public $greetingCardCharge;
    public $amount;
    public $discount;
    public $quantity;
    public $productPrice = 0;
    public $TotalAmount;
    public $overallDiscount;

    public $packagingDetails;
    public $specialInstruction;
    public $productId;
    public $customerId;
    public $specialDeliveryAddress;
    public $deliveryDate;
    public $deliveryTime;

    public $paymentType;
    public $remarks;
    public $supplierId;
    public $deliveryAgentId;

    public $products;
    public $dAgents;
    public $dSuppliers;

    public $unit;
    public $unitAmount;

    public $customers;

    public $existCustomer = False;
    public $newCustomer = False;

    public $orders = [];
    public $selectedProductId = 0;
    public $selectedProductIds = [];

    public function oldCustomer()
    {
        $this->existCustomer = !($this->existCustomer);
        $this->newCustomer = False;
        $this->title = "";
        $this->email = "";
        $this->phone = "";
        $this->customers = Customer::all();
    }

    public function createCustomer()
    {
        $this->newCustomer = !($this->newCustomer);
        $this->customerId = "";
        $this->existCustomer = False;
    }

    protected $rules = [
        'customerId' => 'nullable|',
        'specialDeliveryAddress' => 'nullable|',
        'deliveryDate' => 'required|',
        'deliveryTime' => 'required|',
        'paymentType' => 'required|',
        'remarks' => 'nullable|',
        'supplierId' => 'required|',
        'deliveryAgentId' => 'required|',
        'deliveryCharge' => 'required|numeric',
        'packagingDetails' => 'nullable|string',
        'packagingCharge' => 'nullable|numeric',
        'greetingCardCharge' => 'nullable|numeric',
        'specialInstruction' => 'nullable|string',
    ];

    public function saveOrder()
    {
        $data = $this->validate();
        // dd($data);
        foreach ($this->orders as $or) {
            $order = new Order();
            $order->product_id = $or['productId'];
            if ($this->customerId) {
                $order->customer_id = $data['customerId'];
            }
            $order->supplier_id = $data['supplierId'];
            $order->delivery_agent_id = $data['deliveryAgentId'];
            $order->special_delivery_address = $data['specialDeliveryAddress'];
            $order->delivery_charge = $data['deliveryCharge'];
            $order->packaging_details = $data['packagingDetails'];
            $order->packaging_charge = $data['packagingCharge'];
            $order->greeting_card_charge = $data['greetingCardCharge'];
            $order->special_instruction = $data['specialInstruction'];
            $order->delivery_date = $data['deliveryDate'];
            $order->delivery_time = $data['deliveryTime'];
            $order->amount = $or['amount'];
            $order->payment_type = $data['paymentType'];
            $order->discount = $or['discount'];
            $order->remarks = $data['remarks'];
            $order->status = 0;

            if ($this->newCustomer) {
                $data2 = $this->validate([
                    'title' => 'required|string|min:2|max:100',
                    'phone' => 'required|string|min:6|max:11',
                    'email' => 'required|email|unique:customers',
                    'deliveryAddress' => 'required|string|min:2|max:200',
                ]);
                $data2 = (object) $data2;
                $customer = new Customer();
                $customer->name = $data2->title;
                $customer->phone = $data2->phone;
                $customer->email = $data2->email;
                $customer->address = $data2->deliveryAddress;
                $save = $customer->save();

                $this->customerId = Customer::where('email', $data2->email)
                    ->where('phone', $data2->phone)
                    ->select('id')
                    ->first();
                $id = $this->customerId->id;
                if ($this->customerId) {
                    $order->customer_id = $id;
                }
            }
            $save = $order->save();
        }
        if ($save) {
            session()->flash('status', 'Delivery Agent successfully added!');
            return redirect()->route('order.index');
        } else {
            session()->flash('failed', 'DeliveryAgent added failed!');
            return redirect()->route('order.create');
        }
    }

    public function remove($index)
    {
        array_splice($this->orders, $index, 1);
        array_splice($this->selectedProductIds, $index, 1);
    }

    public function updatedselectedProductId()
    {
        $product = Product::join('units', 'products.unit_id', 'units.id')
            ->where('products.id', $this->selectedProductId)->first();
        $this->orders[] = [
            'productId' => $product->id,
            'productName' => $product->title,
            'quantity' => $product->amount,
            'unit' => $product->unit,
            'discount' => 0,
            'price' => $product->sell_price,
            'amount' => $product->sell_price,
        ];
        $this->selectedProductIds[] = $this->selectedProductId;
        $this->selectedProductId = 0;
        $this->totalAmount += $product->sell_price;
    }

    public function updatedOrders($value, $name)
    {
        if (Str::endsWith($name, '.quantity')) {
            $index = Str::before($name, '.');
            if (is_numeric($value)) {
                $this->orders[$index]['amount'] = $this->orders[$index]['price'] * $value;
            }
        }
        if (Str::endsWith($name, '.discount')) {
            $index = Str::before($name, '.');
            if (is_numeric($value)) {
                $amount = $this->orders[$index]['quantity'] * $this->orders[$index]['price'];
                $this->orders[$index]['amount'] = $amount - ($amount * $value / 100);
            }
        }
        $this->totalAmount += $this->orders[$index]['amount'];
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->products = Product::all();
        $this->dAgents = DeliveryAgent::all();
        $this->dSuppliers = Supplier::all();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.order.create');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're combining wire:model="" and Value="". I would recommend changing it to wir:model completely.

Also it looks like your root div is not closing, and this is required for Livewire.

Comment: What do you mean by wir:model ?

Comment: Inside your blade form. I think the input fields are bugging because some inputs have both the value tag and the wire:model tag. Both change the value. 

It is just a guess because I had the same type of bugging form using both value and wire:model

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution for you, I hope it's not late for this.

I had to reproduce you project, create database, tables (i ommit some things to make it faster).

Your problem is the `id` in the inputs, just remove it from all inputs and everything should work, if works for me, works for you.